# Swift how to filter 2 array

Tags: arrays, swift, swiftui

I'm new in Swift, and I can't figure out how to filter these 2 arrays

```
var arrayOfFavoriteRoomsId = ["1", "2"]
var arrayOfRooms = [
    VoiceRoom(id: "1", title: "Room1", description:"Test room1"), 
    VoiceRoom(id: "2", title: "Room2", description:"Test room2"), 
    VoiceRoom(id: "3", title: "Room3", description:"Test room3")
]
```

The final array should look like this

```
var filteredArray = [
        VoiceRoom(id: "1", title: "Room1", description:"Test room1"), 
        VoiceRoom(id: "2", title: "Room2", description:"Test room2")
    ]
```

This is what my model looks like

```
struct VoiceRoom: Identifiable, Decodable {
  var id: String
  var title: String
  var description: String
}
```

Comment: You mention both _sorting_ and _filtering_... What do you need exactly?

Comment: Before you can solve a problem, you have to be able to define it clearly. What do you mean, exactly? Are you saying that you want to filter your array `arrayOfRooms` to only contain items who's IDs are in the array `arrayOfFavoriteRoomsId`? If so, stating the goal helps you figure out how to solve it. (See Sergio's answer, assuming that is what you want to do.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```swift
arrayOfRooms.filter { room in
    arrayOfFavoriteRoomsId.contains(room.id)
}
```

If you want to sort them as well:

```swift
arrayOfRooms.filter { room in
    arrayOfFavoriteRoomsId.contains(room.id)
}.sorted(by: { $0.id < $1.id })
```